# How to make the tools in a tower defense game, like the plants in Plants vs Zombie?

Tags: iphone, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I am making a mobile game with Unity.

In Plant vs Zombie, we can place many plants in the scene.

In my game, I need some tools like the plants, so I can click the tools and place them in the scene.

Does anyone know how to make these things in a tower defense game?

Are they just buttons? What should I search to learn this? GUI?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could easily find the solution by googling: "Tower defense game tutorial unity3d". The search result gave me this on the top of the list: http://cgcookie.com/unity/cgc-courses/unity-tower-defense-course/

Answer (score 0):

I dont think they are a buttons, but you can create on object, and give to this object perticular task to preform, and he will repeat this action in a loop, over and over...during the life cycle, and this image or design of hime like  plants, in zombie vs plants, or tower def, can be just a desing of yout object, something similiar like creating a design for android applications.